# Avoid IDs when using jQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui

According to [examples](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/), the tabs block is supposed to contain a list of links, each of which refer to the tab content block by its ID:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Header 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Header 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1">Content of tab 1</div>
  <div id="tab2">Content of tab 2</div>
</div>
```

The problem comes when I need to put it into `<template>` to be able to insert it multiple times into the document. Since ID must be unique across the document, it is not an option for me.

Is there a way of not using IDs with jQuery UI tabs?

Comment: generate ids from js and append them to `<a>`

Comment: @benjaminc, it's an option, but is there a simpler solution?

Comment: You can't do it without `id` because `a` tag and `div` should be connected and only way to do it is `href` and `id`. You can show your content without using jQuery Tab library like showing and hiding `div`s by `index` of elements.